# jQuery UI Tabs, throwing an error on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Hey I am working on a new site build, and one of the main components on the homepage is using jQuery UI Tabs. However for some reason when I have "break on all errors" turned on in firebug, it is throwing an error.

I am not sure exactly what is wrong, from what I can see it should work as intended. Here is a link to the page in question, thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions.

http://www.alleninsurance.ca/home/

Comment: What error is firebug/the page throwing?

Comment: I am not too familiar with firebug when it comes to debugging javascript, however I will list what it is saying. If I turn off break on all errors it works fine.

As far as I can tell it is saying, 

g.ajaxOptions is null

Answer (score 1):

It is wrapped in a try catch statement (below) so it normally silently fails when break on all errors is off.

I dont like what they have done as they could easily use an if statement rather than the try catch but I guess it lends itself to smaller file size.

```
try{g.ajaxOptions.success(i,h)}catch(j){}
```

Comment: Sorry, are you saying it's nothing that is wrong with my code, and that it's just something wrong with the way the ui tabs work?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code. They just use try catch to reduce the code noise in the library e.g if (this && that && alsoThat){ } else {} etc etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this. I feel better knowing that it wasn't something I did wrong :) cheers